# Passing list of values into dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a .txt document with a list of names and numbers, and am trying to pass them into a dictionary in a key/value pair. The list of values looks something like this (it is a vertical list of key/value pairs that has \n new lines between):

File name: "demo.txt"
Contents:

```
Brandon: 115.5
James: 128.87
Joel:
Luke:

Sarah: 827.43
Brandon: 100
Jimmy: xyz
Sue: -153
Sue: 100
Fred: x1y2
This
Should
Not
Get
Included
```

// for blanks, and for non-numeric value, I am trying to skip them -- otherwise, if the name already exists in the dictionary, I'd like to update the value. I've tried the below, but was hoping for some advice:

```
d = {}

lst = []

f = open("demo.txt", "r")

lines = f.readlines()

f.close()


for line in lines:
    lst.append(line.strip().split())


for i in lst:
    if len(i) < 2:
        lst.remove(i)
    else:
        continue

for i in lst:
    try:
        i[0] = i[0][:-1]
    except:
        lst.remove(i)

for i in lst:
    try:
        if len(i) < 2:
            lst.remove(i)
        else:
            i[1] = float(i[1])
    except:
        lst.remove(i)

for i in lst:
   key = i[0]
   value = float(i[1])
   if key in d:
       existing_value = d.get(key)
       value = float(existing_value) + float(value)
       d.update({key: value})
   else:
      d[key] = value

print(d)
```

Comment: Hi staldo, welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly happens when you try the code? What works incorrectly? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66216909/edit) to include additional details so we can effectively help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
d = {}

for line in open("demo.txt"):
    if ':' in line:
        key, value = line.split(":")

        try:
            d[key] = float(value.strip())
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

It skips any lines that don't have a `:` character in them. Otherwise, it splits up the line into a key (before the `:`) and a value (after the `:`), and tries to convert the value into a float. If it fails, it keeps going to the next line. If it succeeds, it either creates a new key in the dict, or updates the existing one.

In terms of advice, a few notes:

1. You use a blank `except` without specifying what type of error you want to catch. This is bad practice. You should generally only catch the type of error you expect. At the very least, do `except Exception` which catches almost every exception, but ignores ones caused by things you don't want to catch, like a kill signal
2. You don't need to read every line into memory, close the file, and then process it. You can process it as you're reading it. This doesn't make a huge difference here, but if you have a massive file, you may not have enough RAM to fit the whole thing into RAM
3. When opening a file to read, it is preferred to use a context manager `with open('demo.txt') as f: f.readline()`, or a loop like I did, so that you don't need to worry about remembering to close the file later - it gets closed automatically
4. I think the biggest thing about your code is that it's super verbose. The power of Python lets you do what you're trying to do in a far shorter, more readable way. If you need to go back at some point, months from now, and read your code, it might take you a few minutes to figure out what it's doing. Shorter code is easier to read (as long as it's not just short for the sake of being short, to the point where it's hard to read)